# Unable to call onclick function multiple times in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have such code, where click on a button randomly generates some statement. It seems to work for first click, but other just don'do nothing. What is wrong with this code:

```
<p id="text"></p>
<button onclick="showAdvice()">Click</button>
<script>
    var advices = ["statement", "another", "other", "third"];
    var choose = Math.floor(Math.random() * advices.length);
    function showAdvice(){
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = advices[choose];
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare function this way:

```
function showAdvice(){
    var choose = Math.floor(Math.random() * advices.length);
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = advices[choose];
}
```

In your case "choose" defined only once and every call of showAdvice() will return same text.